# Troubles with Haldane Shastry Spin Chain

Tags: quantum-spin, spin-models, integrable-systems, spin-chains

I'm actually reading the article of Shastry "Exact  solution  of  an  S=  1/2  Heisenberg  Antiferromagnetic  Chain  with  Long-rnaged  interactions",  Phys.
Rev. Lett. 60, 639 (1988)"
The articles shows how to solve the problem of a long range-inverse squared interacting spin chain, i'm having troubles with equations 5 and 6 of the article, i tried everything but could not find the same result !
if someone knows how it goes, i'm here to discuss,
Thanks !

Comment: It would be best to type the equations into the question (using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) not an image -images of equations and pages are strongly discouraged on Physics SE and Mathjax is the standard ).

Comment: Could you show your work? It isn't clear what having "tried everything" means...